# Drupal 9.2 Install error

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

Drupal 9.2, CiviCRM 5.42
Have read all related issues and followed all patches / notes, including ( but not limited to ) https://github.com/osuosl/snowdrift-civicrm/commit/695dd0384b5d37b97aab674bc30426290dc685d2
It is still happening on the fresh latest Drupal 9.2.6 / CiviCRM 5.4.2 ( tried 5.4.1 and 5.3.5 also ) with scssphp/scssphp:1.6.
PHP Version 7.4.23, Apache/2.4.49 (Fedora)

> Compiling additional files (For full details, use verbose "-v" mode.)
> Compile: Generate CCL wrapper functions
> @php -r 'require_once '''/var/www/html/d9/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::template($GLOBALS[\Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::GLOBAL_VAR]);'
> WARNING: Failed to read compilation-task from COMPOSER_COMPILE_TASK. Please use "composer compile".
> Script @php -r 'require_once '''/var/www/html/d9/vendor/autoload.php'''; Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::import(); \CCL\Tasks::template($GLOBALS[\Civi\CompilePlugin\TaskTransfer::GLOBAL_VAR]);' handling the shell-runner event returned with error code 255

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid file reference (tpl-file=NULL) in /var/www/html/d9/vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/src/Tasks/Template.php:62
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/d9/vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/src/Tasks/Template.php(21): CCL\Tasks\Template::assertFileField()
> #1 /var/www/html/d9/vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/src/Tasks.php(24): CCL\Tasks\Template::compile()
> #2 Command line code(1): CCL\Tasks::template()
> #3 {main}
> thrown in /var/www/html/d9/vendor/civicrm/composer-compile-lib/src/Tasks/Template.php on line 62
> Subcommand @composer compile  returned with error code 255  In ComposerPassthru.php line 72:
> Subcommand @composer compile  returned with error code 255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with environment variables. See https://github.com/civicrm/composer-compile-plugin/issues/17